# Filter large arrays using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm

I have 2 large arrays populated with strings both containing > 150.000 elements

```
const allNew = allArrayOneValues.filter(val => !allArrayTwoValues.includes(val));
```

I need to compare the two arrays like this to find out which elements are not in ArrayTwo yet or to find out which elements to delete from ArrayTwo as they are no longer in ArrayOne.

Filtering here takes around 3 to 5 minutes... is there a way to do a far more efficient compared to find out which values in ArrayOne are not yet in ArrayTwo OR which values are in ArrayTwo which are not in ArrayOne...

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: are the arrays sorted? have you tried to use `Set` or an object?

Comment: No, they contain random values like 1#4#5 and 7#9#100 etc... I have not looked at set yet

Comment: sorted meand ascending or descending value, not necessarily random values.

Comment: This is an algorithm question and since you're using the brute-force approach, it's taking a very long time. Please describe if data has any special properties - (sorted values, all unique values/has duplicates values, min and max value possible, etc) for us to provide the best possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current algorithm is O(m*n) (where m= length of first array, n= length of second array)

Using an efficient data-structure that can do sub-linear lookup, it's possible to this in atleast O(m*lg(n))

So for 150,000 elements, it would be  10 thousand times faster and should take a few milliseconds instead of minutes.

```js
let allArrayOneValues = [1, 2, 4]
let allArrayTwoValues = [3, 9, 2]
let hash = new Set();
allArrayTwoValues.forEach((value) => {
  hash.add(value)
})

const allNew = allArrayOneValues.filter(val => !hash.has(val));
console.log(allNew)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Sachin, this is definitively the accepted answers, works in just a second instead of mins!

Answer (score 1):

use `Set` or `Object` may be a good choice. Here is an example:

```js
// convert allArrayTwoValues to Object.
const tmp = allArrayTwoValues.reduce((prev, item) => { prev[item] = true; return prev; }, {});
// filter values not in allArrayTwoValues
const allNew = allArrayOneValues.filter(item => !tmp[item]);
```

Comment: Could you add more detail about how/why this works

Comment: I also do not understand how this would work. In ArrayTwo, I need to add the values from ArrayOne which are missing. Then on top of that, I need to find out which values exist in ArrayTwo which are no longer in ArrayOne (elements that may have been removed from ArrayOne) - so that after these 2 comparisons, I can add elements to ArrayTwo and remove certain ones and then ArrayTwo will match ArrayOne

Comment: @thomas Hi, i have updated the code. the code only filter the values are not in arrayTwo. There is need to do more thing like that.